# Seq[AnyVal] returned as type instead of Seq[Int]

Tags: scala

I define the following List of tuples:

```
var temps = Seq(("Spain", Seq(68,70,73,75)),       
                ("Trinidad",Seq(87,83,88,84,88)), 
                ("England",Seq(52,55,58,57.5)),
                ("Eritrea",Seq(90,91.3,88,91)))
```

and the resulting type is as follows:

```
temps: Seq[(String, Seq[AnyVal])] = List((Spain,List(68, 70, 73, 75)), (Trinidad,List(87, 83, 88, 84, 88)), (England,List(52.0, 55.0, 58.0, 57.5)), (Eritrea,List(90.0, 91.3, 88.0, 91.0)))
```

My question is why the type of temps is inferred as `Seq[(String, Seq[AnyVal])]` rather than `Seq[(String, Seq[Int])] or Seq[(String, Seq[Double])]` which is what one would expect ?

I am a Scala newbie so pardon me if there is a simple explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how type inference works. Scala can infer type in a context/declaration scope, but not across contexts as in here. For example this works:

```
scala> val ss = Seq(Seq(1, 1.2))
ss: Seq[Seq[Double]] = List(List(1.0, 1.2))
```

Although we have both `Int` and `Double`, `Int` gets promoted up.
However, this does not work:

```
scala> val ss = Seq(Seq(1, 1.2), Seq(2, 2))
ss: Seq[Seq[AnyVal]] = List(List(1.0, 1.2), List(2, 2))
```

because first list becomes `Seq[Double]` and second one - `Seq[Int]`. To find common super type scala reverts to `Seq[AnyVal]`.

You can explicitly annotate the declaration to help compiler resolve the ambiguity:

```
scala> val ss: Seq[Seq[Double]] = Seq(Seq(1, 1.2), Seq(2, 2))
ss: Seq[Seq[Double]] = List(List(1.0, 1.2), List(2.0, 2.0))
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So by across contexts you mean multiple items ?

Comment: yes, in some cases a type is inferred and fixed in function declaration and can be helpful in resolving types of other elements - as in functions with multiple argument lists.

Comment: for example http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html - see Multiple Parameter Lists -> 3.For type inference.